# How to generate random uid and token in django without generating models and logins of user

Tags: django, authentication, token, rest, djoser

I have to activate user without models. I am not generating any user. I want to generate random uid and token. for that I want to pass this uid and token in **/activate/{uid}/{token}** link. I created this code in view for generate uid and token:

```
class ActivateUser(CreateAPIView):
    def get(self, request, uid, token, format = None):
        payload = {'uid': uid, 'token': token}
        print("payload : " , payload)

        url = "http://localhost:8000/api/auth/users/activate/"
        response = request.post(url, data = payload)

        if response.status_code == 204:
            return Response({}, response.status_code)
        else:
            return Response(response.json())
```

For activate user I generate this link in url

```
    re_path('api/auth/users/activate/(?P<uid>[\w-]+)/(?P<token>[\w-]+)/',ActivateUser.as_view())
```

create activation url in setting.py

```
    DJOSER = {'ACTIVATION_URL': 'activate/{uid}/{token}/',
}
```